# Updating old Set with a new one in hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I have some problem with hibernate updating object:

```
public class SearchType implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7909889858492050282L;

    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private Set<SearchTypeParameters> parameters = new HashSet<SearchTypeParameters>();

    public SearchType() {}

    public SearchType(SearchTypeDTO typeDto) {
         id = typeDto.getId();
         name = typeDto.getName();
         Set<SearchTypeParametersDTO> parametersDTOs = typeDto.getParameters();
         Set<SearchTypeParameters> parameters = new HashSet<SearchTypeParameters>(parametersDTOs.size());
         for (SearchTypeParametersDTO parameterDTO : parametersDTOs) {
              parameters.add(new SearchTypeParameters(parameterDTO));
         }
         this.parameters = parameters;

    }
    //getters and setters
}


public class SearchTypeParameters implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7312128186599122114L;

    private int parameterId;
    private String searchCriteria;
    private String value;
    private SearchType type;

    public SearchTypeParameters() {}

    public SearchTypeParameters(SearchTypeParametersDTO searchParametersDto) {
         parameterId = searchParametersDto.getParameterId();
         searchCriteria = searchParametersDto.getSearchCriteria();
         value = searchParametersDto.getValue();
    }
    //getters and setters
}
```

DTO classes are used to prevent GWT ecxeption with serialization of PersistentSet.

I have no problems when trying to add a new or delete an old object.

But when I tried to update an object:

```
public void updateSearchType(SearchTypeDTO typeDto) throws GwtException {
    try {
        CommonConfig.getBean(SearchTypeDao.class).deleteSearchTypeParameters(typeDto.getId());
        SearchType type = new SearchType(typeDto);
        for (SearchTypeParameters parameter : type.getParameters()) {
            parameter.setSearchType(type);
        }
        CommonConfig.getBean(SearchTypeDao.class).updateSearchType(type);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error(e, e);
        throw new GwtException(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Old records of SearchTypeParameters are deleted normally, but when it creates new ones, only fields with ID are filled, searchCriteria  and value fields are filled with nulls. I checked that `Set<SearchTypeParameters>` to update is filled with proper values.

Here is update method:

```
public void updateSearchType(SearchType type) throws Exception {
    Object merge = getCurrentSession().merge(type);
    getCurrentSession().saveOrUpdate(merge);
}
```

Thanks for attention, I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was quite obvious. I used cascade="save-update". Changing it to cascade="all"
fixed my problem.